# serialization and de-serialization of an object in Swift3

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization

I want to know if there is a possibility of make a serialization and de-serialization of an object in swift 3.

I have an object like this:

```
class Credentials{
    var username:String;
    var password:String;
    init(){
        username = "";
        password = "";
    }
}
```

I want to transform this class into a json (and vice versa ) to send it through HTTP post.

I don't want to use Third party libraries.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Whats the problem? just make method for them? you can init the class with json

Comment: Usually in Objective-C, we declare (and code) `-(id)initWithJSONDict:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict` and for the transformation, it depends (string representation, NSData one, dictionary one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it's not necessary to use a class, a struct is sufficient.

Simple solution with an failable initializer expecting a JSON string and a variable `jsonRepresentation`

```
struct Credentials {
   var username = ""
   var password = ""

   init(username: String, password:String) {
      self.username = username
      self.password = password
   }

   init?(json : String) {
      guard let data = json.data(using: .utf8),
         let jsonDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:String],
         let username = jsonDict?["username"],
         let password = jsonDict?["password"] else { return nil }
      self.username = username
      self.password = password
   }

  var jsonRepresentation : String {
     let jsonDict = ["username" : username, "password" : password]
     if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: []),
        let jsonString = String(data:data, encoding:.utf8) {
        return jsonString
     } else { return "" }
  }
}
```